# Show that they can stay on a round table s.t. every child stay near friends.

Tags: combinatorics

> Let there be 2008 children, each of which has at least 1005 friends among the 2017 other children. Show that they can sit at a round table so that every child sits between two friends.

I tried to solve for 8 children and generalize for 2018, but it's too difficult.

Comment: Define "near friends."  Does that mean "adjacent to at least one friend"?

Comment: I don't believe this.  Suppose the children belong to two groups, the Jets and the Sharks, each with $1009$ members.  Every pair of Jets are friends, every pair of Sharks are friends, and no Jet is a friend of any Shark.  Each child has $1008$ friends, so the condition is satisfied.  All the Jets must sit together, but the two on the ends must sit next to a Shark.  Have you made a typo somewhere?

Comment: @saulspatz I wrote 2018 instead 2008. I am so sorry.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like the general statement is for $2n$ children who each have at least $n+1$ friends, and the Jets-Sharks counterexample doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So apparently the answer is yes and can be found in: Dirac, G. A. (1952), "Some theorems on abstract graphs", Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society, 3rd Ser., 2: 69–81.

What you can do is create a graph where the children are vertices and there is an edge between both vertices if the children are friends. You now need to find a cycle which only goes through every vertex once. This is called a Hamiltonian cycle, and a graph which has a Hamiltonian cycle is called a Hamiltonian graph.

In the article Dirac shows that every graph with $n\geq 3$ vertices such that every vertex has degree larger than $n/2$ is Hamiltonian. (See the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path)